# Data insert into Excel file

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

I am writing the data from the table to an Excel file. The first time it executes, it inserts the data into the table but does not make it into the file, but when the second, 3rd, 4th etc. the app is executed, it writes to the file, and I am not seeing why it doesn't immediately after the first execution.

```
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
     // the query or stored procedure name for the database
     string sqlQuery = "SELECT [PerDiemEntityId], [TripNumber] as [Trip #] ,[CustomerReferenceNumber] as [Customer Reference Number] ,[CustomerLocation] as [Customer Location] ,[EquipmentNumber] as [Equipment] ,[ArrivalTimeActual] as [Arrival Time Actual] ,[LastFreeDate] as [Last Free Date],[EquipmentAvailableDate] as [Equipment Available Date],[EquipmentChargeableDays] as [Equipment Chargeable Days],[PerDiemEquipmentChargeAmount] as [Equipment Charge Amt],[StorageChargeableDays] as [Storage Chargeable Days] ,[StorageChargeAmount] as [Storage Chargeable Amt],[NotifyDate] as [Notify Date],[OutgateDate] as [Outgate Date],[DestinationId] as [Destination ID],[OriginId] as [Origin ID],[CustomerId] as [Customer ID] FROM[LogisticsPerDiem].[dbo].[PerDiemEntity]";

     // create a datatable
     DataTable dataTable = loadExternalDataSet(sqlQuery);

     // create a WorkSheet
     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
     worksheet.Cells["A1:O1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
     worksheet.Column(1).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(1).Width = 17;

     worksheet.Column(2).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(2).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(3).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(3).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(4).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(4).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(5).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(5).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(6).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(6).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(7).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(7).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(8).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(8).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(9).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(9).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(10).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(10).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(11).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(11).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(12).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(12).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(13).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(13).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(14).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(14).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(15).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(15).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(16).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(16).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(17).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Column(17).Width = 15;

     worksheet.Column(6).Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
     worksheet.Column(7).Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
     // worksheet.Column(9).Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
     worksheet.Cells["J2:J10000"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00";
     worksheet.Cells["L2:L10000"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00";
     worksheet.Cells["G2:G10000"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
     worksheet.Cells["H2:H10000"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
     worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

     string filePath = "C:\\temp\\PerDiemCharges" + "09162019" + ".xlsx" ;

     // Instead of converting to bytes, you could also use FileInfo
     FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
     excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);
}

// method for retrieving data from the database and return it as a datatable
DataTable loadExternalDataSet(string sqlQuery)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnStr"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connectionstring))
    {
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

No errors I look to see the results from the table inserted into the file when the app is executed

Comment: First, your try/catch is swallowing any errors in the loadExternalDataSet function. So you may have errors you don't see. Second, do you have the Excel file open when you run your process? You won't be able to write to an open Excel file. Third, if you do have errors then you may have orphaned instances of Excel running that retain a hold on the file. Look in your Task Manager to see if multiple Excel instances are running that may have a hold on the file.

Comment: No the file isn't open, I have had it opened and it does of course throw the error not being able to write to file that is being used. The data is written to the file only after it has been ran again.

Comment: Also is there a better way to write this so it isn't so long and extensive, it write it to the file with proper formatting just seems bulky, is there a way to do it with linq?

Comment: public async Task GoAsync(DateTime startDate)
        {
            var customer = new CustomerPerDeimCharges();
            customer.CustomerCharges();
            var reportData = GetReportData(startDate).ToArray();
            var reportDataWithEquipment = _equipChargeManager.SetEquipmentChargeData(reportData).ToArray();
            var reportDataWithStorage = _storageChargeManager.SetStorageChargeData(reportDataWithEquipment).ToArray();

            await _uow.PerDiemEntityRepository.AddRangeAsync(reportDataWithStorage);
            await _uow.SaveChangeAsync();
        }

Comment: What if you add `if (datatable.Rows.Count == 0) throw new DataException("Data table is empty!");` after the line where you call `loadExternalDataSet`?  Did you run this code in a unit test?  If not you should to help isolate the problem.  To shorten you code do a `for` look to set the column properties.